# git Commit, after overwriting the cloned version

Tags: xcode, git, repository, clone, local

I was working in one project file detached from the remote repository for a while, I would like to commit my changes to the old existing repository now.

I have cloned the old version:

```
git clone <repository path>
```

How I can merge my new changes? Overwriting the local git folder and run:

```
git commit
```

cause me some errors.

tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add your files to the list of changes to be committed.

You could say `git add myfile.txt anotherfile.txt`, or, you could add all files with `git add *`.
Or, you could have Git automatically add file changes to a Git commit by saying `git commit -a`.

To merge your changes into the remote repo, you need to run `git push origin master`.

Comment: The remote repository have around 50 files my latest project file have around 80 in addition to the new files the old once are modified also. what I need to do once I clone the remote repository? I could follow the basic git documentation but in this case I am trying to commit to an existing repository which wasn't updated for a while. I don't need any file from the remote for this project but the remote contains other project files which I shouldn't overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

After I cloned my git repository, I overwrite my latest on the local repository then I run

```
git commit -a
git push
```

this probably not the best way to deal with it. But if the changes are a lot before they are checked in  this can be an option.